# Category or page

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

In Wordpress I have set my permalinks to display the category and the blogtitle in the url. But I also have a page (with subpages) that have the same name as a category which causes a conflict. Is there a way to solve this or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only two options :

- change your page permalink
- change your category slug

Comment: That is indeed what we considered. Thanks!